# How to call an anonymous function stored as a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to dynamically set page title in AngularJs. 
I'm using angular-ui router and stateHelper.

So I have this in my main template:

```
<title ng-bind="pageTitle"></title>
```

And this in my ui-router:

```
{
    name: 'show',
    url: '/:id',
    title: function($stateParams){
       return 'Showing '+$stateParams.id;
    }
}
```

Then this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams)
{
     //set page title
     if(angular.isFunction(toState.title))
     {
         var callBack = toState.title; //this is the anonymous function
         //I expect the anonymous function to return the title
         $rootScope.pageTitle = callBack;
     }else{
         $rootScope.pageTitle = toState.title;
     }
}
```

The Challenge:
`var callBack = toState.title;`

returns a string like this "function($stateParams){return 'Showing '+$stateParams.id;}"

How do I execute this function and also respect the parameters `dependency injected` parameters passed along with it (unknown number of DI)

**NB: I am so scared of `eval` and wouldn't like to use it :(**

Comment: In a nutshell. an anonymous function like this `function($stateParams){
       return 'Showing '+$stateParams.id;
    }` is passed to another function as a string, how do I call the anonymous function along with all its injected parameters

Comment: There's no way to do this without `eval`. If it is you who defines `title` format, it could be changed to a degree when it doesn't require `eval`.

Comment: how do I even use eval in this case? any example?

Comment: In your example it appears that `title` is a function and not a string. If this is so, it can be treated with $injector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function can be invoked with relevant dependencies with [`$injector.invoke`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#invoke):

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams)
{
     if(angular.isFunction(toState.title) || angular.isArray(toState.title))
     {
         $rootScope.pageTitle = $injector.invoke(toState.title);
     }else{
         $rootScope.pageTitle = toState.title;
     }
}
```

As any other DI-enabled function, `title` should be annotated accordingly, it may be either [a function](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation) or [an array](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation).

Comment: this is exactly  what I was looking for! Thanks a bunch. Dough `$stateParams` returns empty object when i go to URL with param like /product/1, but I will find a way around it. Was able to inject other services successfully

Comment: Notice that $stateParams [isn't exactly the same](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service) as $state.params.

Comment: $state.params still doesn't work but works when I use `$stateChangeSuccess` instead of `$stateChangeStart` $stateParams also works

Answer (score 0):

You can inject $stateParams into the controller (where the $rootScope.$on statement in) first, and call

> toState.title($stateParams);

By the way, you can consider use a better solution to handle "dynamic title". Check the way this project use: https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp

Comment: Thanks for responding. This will not work since I am unaware of the parameter injected. It could be a service or $state or just anything.

Comment: Well, I don't understand. if you pass $stateParams into your controller function, you will get $stateParams object surely. Doesn't it the way injection works?

Comment: What I am trying to say is.. what if I decide to do this instead `title : function($state, $stateParams, UserService){
       return 'Welcome '+UserService.username;
    }` I want to be able to inject anything and call the function later